# AD DirSync and Office 365 remove password replication from some users

Tags: microsoft-office-365

My current setup is AD > DirSync > office365 but i would like some remote users to be in cloud only, how would i do this? as i want them to have the freedom to change their passwords themselves without having to be on the domain

```
EDIT
```

Also the users are already existing domain users with mailboxes

Comment: Have you tried making user accounts in the Office 365 admin portal so that they are cloud only? Wait, are you saying that the users that you want to be cloud only are currently in your on-premise organization? Are you trying to move their mail to Office 365 and then get rid of their on-premise domain accounts?

Comment: users are currently on premise domain/office 365 for email, i want to break the link for passwords replication as they remote users now

Comment: Where are their mailboxes currently stored, on premise or in Exchange Online?

Comment: exchange online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, there is no official documentation from Microsoft on how to do this, you will have to hack your way through to convert "Synced with Active Directory" users to "In cloud" uses.

Your hacking should be as follow:

1. Take a backup of the users data before doing anything.
2. Deactivate DirSync, use the steps here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2619062
3. Connect PowerShell to Office 365, user the steps here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975125.aspx.
4. For each user you want to change to "In Cloud", use the following command

   Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName  -ImmutableID  $null
5. If the users that you changed to "In Cloud" are no longer needed in your local Active Directory, disable/delete them. If they're still needed, filter them out using the following: http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenkumar/archive/2014/04/11/how-to-do-filtering-in-dirsync.aspx
6. Re-activate DirSync.

There is a nice guideline with a script that you may use if you have a large bulk of users you want to convert here: https://blog.westmonroepartners.com/migrating-your-dirsync-domain-for-office-365/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adjusting the filtering options of ADSYNC? if the users are in the same OU you can filter out that OU, or you cold add a custom attribute to your users and filter them out if the sync that way. there are a couple of nice articles on filtering here:

https://dirteam.com/dave/2015/04/06/azure-active-directory-synchronization-filtering-part-1/